Primitive $5$-th root of unity $\zeta$ such that $\zeta^{-1}+\zeta\in\mathbb F_5$ but $\zeta\notin\mathbb F_5$
Consider the finite field $\mathbb F_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $5$-th root of unity lying in some extension field of $\mathbb F_5$. Since $x^4=1$ for every $x\in\mathbb F_5^{\ast}$, it follows that $\zeta\notin\mathbb F_5$. Is it possible that $\zeta^{-1}+\zeta\in\mathbb F_5$ ? It so, what is the value of $\zeta^{-1}+\zeta$ ?
My attempt If $\lambda=\zeta^{-1}+\zeta\in\mathbb F_5$, then $\zeta$ is a solution of $x^2-\lambda x+1=0$. This polynomial is irreducible for $\lambda=1$ and for $\lambda=4$, so $\zeta^{-1}+\zeta\in\{1,4\}$ ?

Note that over $\mathbb{F}_5$ the only 5th root is $1$, because $x^5-1=(x-1)^5$. So it doesn't really makes sense to talk about primitive 5th roots over $\mathbb{F}_5$.

$\zeta\notin\mathbb F_5$ but $\zeta\in\mathbb E$, where $\mathbb E$ is some extension of $\mathbb F$.

@schiepy As every $5$-th root of unity is a power of $1$ I'd say that $1$ is the only primitive $5$-th root of unity. It makes sense but it's not very interesting

@boaz You are just wrong, all $5$-th roots of unity over $\mathbb{F}_5$ lie in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

@boaz The identity $x^5-1=(x-1)^5$ obviously still holds in any extension field, if it holds in $\mathbb{F_5}$. Take any extension of $\mathbb{F_5}$, there will be no $5$-th roots of unity except $1$.

I see, because $x^5-1$ is separable?

@boaz Exactly the opposite, it is NOT separable in fields of characteristic $5$.

In response to your previous question we explained that is an $n$th root of unity $\zeta$ has the property that $\lambda\in\Bbb{F}_q$, then either $n\mid q-1$ (this was in Schiepy's comment), when $\zeta\in\Bbb{F}_q$, or $n\mid q+1$. Here $q=5$ so the fourth roots of unity live in $\Bbb{F}_5$, and the sixth as well as third roots of unity have $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\in\Bbb{F}_5$. May be you didn't understand all the details of the answers? In that case it might be worth your while to pinpoint a step that you find troubling!

Thanks @Jyrki Lahtonen. I mistakenly thought that for every $n$, there exists an extension of $\mathbb F$ that includes a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

May I say that there exists an extension field of $\mathbb F$ that includes a primitive $n$-th root of unity iff $p\nmid n$, where $p$ is the characteristic of $\mathbb F$?

Yes. That is correct. Even more can be said. If $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $n\mid p^m-1$, then a root of unity $\zeta$ of order $n$ generates the field of size $p^m$. In other words, $\Bbb{F}p(\zeta)=\Bbb{F}{p^m}$. This also means that minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$ has degree $m$.
